# Using rep() function in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

The following code repeats a line three times, but the rep() function is inside of a for loop. Based on the design i would expect it to repeat the string from humps three times,  but instead it repeats the whole line. Im confused as to how this happens. is it becuase of the for loop? or is it the str_c() or cat() arguement?

```
library(stringr)

humps <- c("five", "four", "three", "two", "one", "no")
for (i in humps) {
  cat(str_c("Alice the camel has ", rep(i, 3), " humps.",
    collapse = "\n"
  ), "\n")
  if (i == "no") {
    cat("Now Alice is a horse.\n")
  } else {
    cat("So go, Alice, go.\n")
  }
  cat("\n")
}
```

Comment: I believe it is the `str_c()`. Notice if you do `str_c("a", rep("b", 3), "c")` you get "abc" repeated three times. It would be this line from the help file: "Short arguments are recycled to the length of the longest."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about your intended output, but I took a crack at it anyway:

```r
humps <- c("five", "four", "three", "two", "one", "no")
for (i in humps) {
  cat(paste0("Alice the camel has ", paste(rep(i, 3), collapse = " "), " humps."), "\n")
  if (i == "no") {
    cat("Now Alice is a horse.\n")
  } else {
    cat("So go, Alice, go.\n")
  }
  cat("\n")
}
```

The key is to wrap the `rep` in a `paste` function with a `collapse` argument. This turns the list into a string. Otherwise, `str_c`—I'm also not sure why you used that function here—runs once per element of the list.

That'll print:

```
Alice the camel has five five five humps. 
So go, Alice, go.

Alice the camel has four four four humps. 
So go, Alice, go.

Alice the camel has three three three humps. 
So go, Alice, go.

Alice the camel has two two two humps. 
So go, Alice, go.

Alice the camel has one one one humps. 
So go, Alice, go.

Alice the camel has no no no humps. 
Now Alice is a horse.
```